# What is 'D' programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, d

What is 'D' programming language? People started developing application using this language? who found? Can I know more about this new programming language?

Comment: these are the droids you are looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(programming_language)

Comment: As pointed out, the main site should answer most of your questions. It also has a forum in case you have more. And this language is hardly new, now...

Comment: Did you try typing "What is ‘D’ programming language?" into google, maybe?

Answer (score 7):

The web site is at http://dlang.org

Answer (score 5):

> The D programming language, also known simply as D, is an object-oriented, imperative, multi-paradigm system programming language designed by Walter Bright of Digital Mars. It originated as a re-engineering of C++, but even though it is predominantly influenced by that language, it is not a variant of it. D has redesigned some C++ features and has been influenced by concepts used in other programming languages, such as Java, C#, and Eiffel. [[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28programming_language%29)]